# API Request not working in ajax but working in POSTMAN

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-204

Im trying to make a post request with one parameter in AJAX to a local server. When I execute the request in postman it seems to work perfectly fine but when I do it with AJAX it sends over two requests one as a 204 and another one as a 404 which seems very strange:

```
<-- OPTIONS /price/current
api_1       |   --> OPTIONS /price/current 204 1ms 
api_1       |   <-- POST /price/current
api_1       |   --> POST /price/current 404 1ms -
```

The actual AJAX request is the following:

```
getBtc = async()  => {
     return await fetch("http://localhost:3001/price/current",{
         method: 'POST',
         headers: {
             'Content-Type':'application/json'

         },
         body: JSON.stringify({
             'symbol':'eth'
         })
     })          
     .then(res => {
         console.log(res)
         if (res.success) {
           this.setState({ priceBTC : res.data[0].price })
         }
     })
```

The console log specifies a 200 response with te following info:

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:3001/price/btc", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:3001/price/btc"
__proto__: Response
```

Ideally I would be getting back a status code of 200

Comment: Any console output?

Comment: Are you sure that the method is POST and not GET?

Comment: Its a get in the server, modifying it breaks the endpoint though.

Comment: So you should use `method: 'GET'`, no?

Comment: Getting the two responses isn't necessarily weird. That `options` response is just to verify what you are able to do. Does it require any credentials to be passed or a specific format for the body?

Comment: I haven't used postman much but I know that sometimes transforms aren't transparent. For instance ajax automatically transforms POST data objects into query strings. Is there any possibility that postman may be doing something similar?

Comment: You need to implement CORS headers as an OPTIONS request won't get sent unless origin is different (port, protocol, domain etc). Rest clients like Postman are not cors restricted the way browsers are

Comment: changed everything to a get in the server and sacrificed some flexibility. but Im having this issue now, check edit of the post.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
.then(res => res.json())
.then(jsonRes => {
    console.log(jsonRes)
    if (jsonRes.success) {
        this.setState({ priceBTC : jsonRes.data[0].price })
    }
 })
.catch(err => {
    alert('Something went wrong')
});
```

Here we are converting the response `res` into `json` and from that we're accessing the `data[]`